# How to get a string from memory into DTrace script

Tags: pointers, string, dtrace

I have a char* in my DTrace script that I know points to a zero-terminated string. How to access this string?

Is there some function like copyin() that handles zero-terminated strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copyinstr() does exactly that. It accepts a pointer as a parameter, treats it as a pointer to zero-terminated string and returns a copy of that string in kernel memory accessible by the script.

Note that unlike C, DTrace has a string type. copyinstr() returns that type.

See Sun's [Solaris Dynamic Tracing Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-6223/index.html)